# Browsers compatibility - Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, cross-browser

I am trying to make a website. I am getting problem on menu bar...In safari and chrome it works fine but on firefox i see a white gap in menu items. Please check attached screenshots

[image]

and this is my css code and i am using for it:

```
.menu a {
   display:block;
   padding:.7em 2em;
   background:#333;
   color:#ddd;
   text-decoration:none;
   transition:all .3 ease;
}
```

Please help, I tried a lot, also googled stuff but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It kept  giving me error when i inserted code, finally i added screenshot as it was short code...i am really sorry bro I am new to this site

Comment: Please post more css context.

Comment: Also post the html markup, I've converted the image to actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin and border of `.menu a` to `0`.

Comment: Tried...same Thing :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess the anchor container is a list item (li) element? If so, have you removed the margin and padding from those elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a CSS reseter, that resets the user-agent stylesheet.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

From that remove the elements that you do not need such as `abbr` or `acronym`. This code was grabbed [from here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) ..

Answer (score 0):

If your menu is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

where li is inline-block, then write it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li><li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Inline block elements are displayed with a gap between them. Writing the HTML elements with no gap between them makes it disappear.

There are also several CSS fixes, but the HTML "fix" is the most reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use float:

```
float:left;
display:block;
```

Use it in tag `<li>` like in mr.itmitica's sample.
this will force the menu into a line/block.